# Using two Google Analytics trackers on the same page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

I need to be able to use more than one Google Analytics on a page. How can I do that with the async code?

Getting the tracker used to work a bit like that (not sure about the exact code):

```
var tracker2 = _gat.getTracker("tracker2");
tracker2.trackPageView();
```

However with the new async API, it's not possible to retrieve a value, so how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at: http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html#MultipleCommands

*Edit:*

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(
  ['a._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X'],
  ['a._trackPageview'],
  ['b._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X'],
  ['b._trackPageview']
);
```

This creates two Trackers called `a` and `b`

Comment: I already saw this page but it didn't help. There's an example on how to push a command to a different tracker, but not how to create a tracker with a different name.

Comment: If this doesn't help, i guess i misunderstood your question, sorry

Comment: Oh ok I see, I assumed that for `a._setAccount` to work `a` already had to be created. I'm going to give that a try later.